# How can I pass multiple different numbers (ints) into an array using a single textbox? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I want to fill an array with ints and cap it at 20 elements using a single text box and button in a c# GUI. I've tried using a for loop and it just fills all 20 subs with the first number I pass it. I've tried a break statement to exit the loop, but that doesn't work. Here's my code so far:

```
    int theCount = 0;
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[20];

        int num = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(txtBxStats.Text, out num);)
            {
                numbers[i] = num;
                theCount++;
                break;
            }
        }            
        lblNumCount.Text = $"{theCount} / 20";

    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the text you're trying to parse? Your loop just does the same thing 20 times, so it should not be surprising that you get the same result 20 times.

Comment: `int[] numbers = new int[20];` you are creating new array on every button click. You should instead use `List<int>` and declare it outside the Click Event handler. And in Click event you can check Count property of the list before adding new number to it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya if I were to place the array outside of the button click could it work? I should mention I'm required to pass this array parameter to another method..

Comment: @EricLippert Honestly I could just use a simple int.Parse there seeing as the user is only expected to enter a number, and if not, I show them an error message. I've just been trying to mess with every aspect of the code to see if anything sticks.

Comment: Yes... it will work. You don't need for loop too. You just check the value of  `theCount` variable before adding item to array and if it is less than the array lenght then add item to array else do not add.

Comment: Do you want to add a single number, parsed from the `txtBxStats.Text` each time the user clicks the button (up to 20)?

Comment: Please give an example of what the text box contains. @EricLippert is right you are parsing the same value of the text box for each loop iteration. You can only get the same value.

Comment: @RufusL Correct. The idea is every time you enter a number into the text box and click the button it adds that number into the array (max 20) then I'm meant to pass that to another method to calculate the sum, largest number, lowest number, and the average of all the numbers.

Comment: @Kevin text box can contain any valid integer. for example, 89 or 140.

Comment: @JeremyJames - so do you want it to add a new number every time the button is clicked?

Comment: @Kevin Correct.

Comment: I don't get the problem but I do feel like you don't understand some concepts important for programming. You need to understand how [variable scoops work](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx).

Comment: OK, then this code is very wrong but you can fix it. What you need to do is make a list of numbers -- NOT AN ARRAY, a list -- and it must be at *class scope*, NOT local scope, and then add the number to the list until there are twenty numbers in the list.  You have a completely wrong idea about what loops are for. Loops are for making the *machine* do the same thing 20 times, not the *user*.  The user will do whatever thing they do without any loop!

Comment: @EricLippert - why not an array?

Comment: @EricLippert Maybe I shouldn't divulge this, but I'm a student. I've used lists before but since we technically haven't learned that in class yet, I'm not allowed to use them for any exercises.

Comment: @FilipCordas you are correct, I'm a month into my c# coding class and can only use the tools my instructor has set for my exercises.

Comment: That is an entirely reasonable thing to divulge: **it helps us answer your question better**.  There are lots of reasons to use lists over arrays: to begin with, lists can grow or shrink in size, unlike arrays. They can report how many items are in them, unlike arrays. And so on. It is common for instructors to have the belief that arrays are "easier" or "more fundamental" than other collection types; I disagree with this belief, but if your instructor wants to put restrictions on what techniques you use, follow that rubric.

Comment: @JeremyJames If you are interested in learning what the issue with your code was you should read the short article I linked in the comment.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for that! I'm sure my instructor will want us to use lists in the future once we've covered classes and objects, we're just not there yet.

Comment: @FilipCordas I will check that out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do it every time the button is pressed your code would need to look more like below. I moved the array outside of the click event (class level) and you don't need the for loop.

```
private int theCount = 0;
private int[] numbers = new int[20];

private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = 0;

    if (theCount < 20 && int.TryParse(txtBxStats.Text, out num))
    {
        numbers[theCount] = num;
        theCount++;                
    }

    lblNumCount.Text = $"{theCount} / 20";
}
```

Comment: That should be `theCount < 20` or on the 21st click you'll get an out of bounds exception.

Comment: @juharr - thanks I think I moved the theCount++ to the end of the if statement and forgot to update that.

Answer (score 0):

If you intention is to add the number in the text box each the button is clicked, then the button click should be something similar to below;

```
    int theCount = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[20];

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numToAdd;

        if (int.TryParse(txtNumToAdd.Text, out numToAdd))
        {
            if (theCount < 20)
            {
                theCount++;

                numbers[theCount -1] = numToAdd;

                lblNumCount.Text = string.Format("{0} / 20", theCount.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot exceed 20 numbers!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Though this is a good attempt, a better practice would be to disable the text box after 20 numbers. Don't tell the user they're doing something wrong if you can prevent them from doing it.